# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func

Tags: driver, device-driver, wdk

I am trying to compile a windows driver using winddk. I am keep getting the mentioned error. I have already added USE_LIBCMT = 1 to my SOURCE file. However, I m still getting the same error. Can anyone tell me what I must be missing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly don't want to `USE_LIBCMT` from a (kernel?!) driver. Windows kernel drivers don't have any kind of C `stdio.h` functions available, other than a very limited set of C runtime functions for basic string operations (check `ntoskrnl.exe` exports).

Of course there is the chance that you are writing a user mode driver (WDF), but even then you don't really want to do what you are trying.

The complete `SOURCES` file and some code snippets would be appreciated, though. Of course you can leave out source and header file names. Relevant are mostly the defines and the type of driver you are trying to build.

Comment: @stus_access: you got me. I had got it wrong. I was trying to link a user mode library into a kernel driver. That is why I was facing this issue. I have got a user mode library for which source is not available. I wanted to add that library to kernel mode driver. The only possible option I can see is put wrappers for functions which are not part of ntoskrnl.exe. Functions like iob_func or fprintf. Let me know if you think there is any other better option. (Thanks)

Comment: @agent.smith: use the `Kd*` set of functions since you are clearly aiming at getting some kind of readable output. The kernel debugger is your friend there ...